# How to import a framework with cocoa pods and swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods, jwplayer

I am trying to add the JWPlayer SDK to my new Swift project using CocoaPods.

I create a new project. Add the following to a Podfile

```
use_frameworks!
target 'JWPlayerTutorial' do
 pod 'JWPlayer-SDK', '~> 2.0'
end
```

I then add an import statement to a view controller:

```
import Pods_JWPlayerTutorial
```

or

```
import JWPlayer_SDK
```

When I try `var player: JWPlayer` I get the error:

```
Use of undeclared type JWPlayer
```

Should I be adding a bridging header? Should I be adding the framework to build phases? Do I need to change linker flag settings? What is the correct import statement to use?

Here is a screenshot of my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Since JWPlayer are all in objective - C, you will need a bridge header.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/intro/getting-started/ for the steps to add JWPlayer SDK in Swift.

Comment: I followed that. I added the framework with a podfile, updated the info.plist. I used use_frameworks! in the podfile so I didn't need to use the import statement. I also didn't change the linker tag as the pod install seemed to change it for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Clean Xcode project. Clear Derived Data. Close Xcode and restart device/simulator. Maybe it should work.